# Firefox canvas getImageData values differ from original image pixel values

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, png, steganography

I want to encode some JSON as RBG values in a png file and read the values in javascript once the image is loaded.  This is the function I am using for the image load.

For each pixel in the image we get 4 bytes corresponding to R, B, G, and A components.  The alpha channel is always 255.  So I ignore that value.  Also, there can be some padding in the image to make it fit the 4 byte boundary required by the above scheme.  I ignore that too.  (Look at the for loop with condition checking for zero values in R, B, G component.

In the code below, img comes from a server that encodes json data into an image.  For the case of this question, the source of the img shouldn't matter.  I can add more details if required.

The pixel values in the image will be something like

```
5B 7B 22 255 64 72 69 255 22 3A 22 255 31 31 22 255 7B 5B 00 255
```

which corresponds to

```
[{"dri":"11"}]
```

This is an example as I cannot share the original image.

```
img.onload = function(e){
    console.log('load successful', e);
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.width = img.width;
    c.height = img.height;
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    console.log(ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled);
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    ctx.strokeStyle=(0,0,0,1);
    ctx.shadowBluer = 0;
    console.log(ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled);
    window.myCtx = ctx;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    window.imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.width, img.height);
    result = [];
    for(i=0, len = imageData.data.length; i < len; i++){
        if((i+1)%4===0 || imageData.data[i] === 0){
            continue;
        }
        result.push(String.fromCharCode(imageData.data[i]));
    }
    elem.innerText = result.join("");
};
```

This code has to work on a random users' browser.  So I cannot tweak any config settings of the browser.  This code works fine in Windows FF, chrome, IE 11, Edge.  Also it works fine in Chrome, Safari in Mac.  But in Firefox on Mac, the values of the pixels are modified slightly.  I am not sure how to fix this.  Any idea to fix this would be awesome.  If this cannot be fixed, if someone can give some reasons on why Firefox on Mac behaves differently, that would be good too.

I believe the issue is due to alpha premultiplying by browsers.  Is there anyway to turn this off?

Comment: That's kind of expected that browsers will not preserve the exact data that is gotten from getImageData (even if it is kinda weird for opaque ones), so stenography through image to be decoded in a canvas is not the best idea. Now, in your code, what is `img` where does it come from? If it is one of the generated png, could you share it? Why do you draw it three times in a row? Why do you putImageData an empty ImageData? And to your issue, did you changed FF's `gfx.color_management.XXXX` preferences? Does modifying your Monitor Display Profile to e.g a generic sRGB Profile modifies the results?

Comment: @Kaiido I am updating the question with these details as it will be relevant for anyone in SO

Comment: Are you really mixing HEX and base10? And for me your code gives `[{"dri11"{[` in both Chrome and FF. https://jsfiddle.net/tq7rL5um/1/

Comment: So [here I rewrote](https://jsfiddle.net/94tL7c2n/) the whole encoding + decoding part, can you confirm you still face the issue on FF for mac, and if so, which version, and the values for `gfx.color_management.XXXX` in `about:config`, along with the Display Profile set by your OS?

Comment: I am sorry.  I did mix hex and base10.  I will check your code in mac